# F# issue when porting some VB.NET code

Tags: f#

I want to convert some VB.NET code for regular expression to F#.
The following code works in VB.NET:

```vb
Dim regOpts As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline
Dim r As New Regex("<a[^>]*href\s*=\s*""?(?<HRef>[^"">\s]*)""?[^>]*>", regOpts)
```

But the corresponding code in F# can not get complied:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
let regOpts: RegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ||| RegexOptions.Singleline
let reg = new Regex("<a[^>]*href\s*=\s*""?(?<HRef>[^"">\s]*)""?[^>]*>", regOpts)
```

I got the compiler error:

> Error: This value is not a function and cannot be applied

I believe F# does NOT recognize the double quote inside double quote, but for VB.NET, it is OK, my code work correctly. Please show me how to modify the F# code, so it can work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape the `"` as `\"` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323829.aspx), instead of the VB.NET escape (that doubles them).

```
let reg = new Regex("<a[^>]*href\s*=\s*\"?(?<HRef>[^\">\s]*)\"?[^>]*>", regOpts)
```

Though a better option might be to change it to a verbatim string literal:

```
let reg = new Regex(@"<a[^>]*href\s*=\s*""?(?<HRef>[^"">\s]*)""?[^>]*>", regOpts)
```

Comment: Hi, Oded:
Thank you very much, my code compiled, but not totally work as expected.
My VB.NET version works correctly with the same data, but F# version give some different result, which is not correct.
The code is used to list the URLs in one web page, the VB.NET version and from Firefox's Web Developer (inspect) get the same URLs, but the result from F# version, all URLs returned seem missing the leading part.
Any idea?

Comment: @JohnJohn - Updated answer. Use a verbatim string literal.

Comment: Hi, Oded:
I have tested, the result is the same.
I can not understand why VB.NET works, but F# is not doing the same job.
But thanks for your kind help!
John

Comment: Hi, Oded: verbatim seems to be a good solution, I fixed the bug in F# for this one, but I have another issue.  I want to ask a new question.

Comment: The verbatim string literal is almost a must for F# and C# regex strings. Without it, you have to escape every back-slash so that it gets treated as a regex escape instead of a string escape. Except for the ones that are supposed to be string escapes. Not fun. "<a[^>]*href\\s*=\\s*\"?(?<HRef>[^\">\\s]*)\"?[^>]*>"